# Assembly language IA32 - move char to int

Tags: assembly, x86

In *CSAPP* exercise 3.4

```
src_t v;
dest_t *p;

*p = (dest_t) v;
```

When `src_t` is `char` and `dest_t` is `int`, the answer is

```
movsbl %al, (%edx)
```

(`v` is stored in `%eax` or `%ax` or `%al`, `p` is stored in `%edx`). And when `src_t` is `char` while `dest_t` is `unsigned`, the answer is

```
movsbl %al, (%edx)
```

too.

Why we have to use `movsbl` instead of `movzl` when `char` type is non-negative?

Comment: It's because the C language standard makes the signedness of `char` implementation-specified and -documented. As such the type `char` may be signed (and require sign-extension) or unsigned (and require zero-extension). It looks like the former was the case.

Comment: The type `char` may be signed or unsigned, it is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of extension instruction reflects the sign of the character type.

gcc lets you control the signedness of characters, so you can see what conversions it would produce for each possibility easily enough.

Source:

```
unsigned char_to_int(char *s) {
    return *s;
}
```

Default output:

```
movl    4(%esp), %eax
movsbl  (%eax), %eax
ret
```

Output with `-funsigned-char`:

```
movl    4(%esp), %eax
movzbl  (%eax), %eax
ret
```

Output with `-fsigned-char`:

```
movl    4(%esp), %eax
movsbl  (%eax), %eax
ret
```

Keep in mind that this is merely the output of one compiler on one platform. Default signedness could be different for a different compiler, or for gcc running on a different platform.